# How to replace name of values in column in R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qboZj.png)

From the photo, in "Make" column, I found some typos, such as Toyota and Toyouta. How to replace the wrong name into the right one in R. Thank you!

Comment: Please post your data as text rather than as a screenshot.  You can use `gsub()`, from base R, for this ...

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this, but I'm a big fan of packages in the [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) and I think it's a great set of packages. You're going to want to install and import tidyverse, and then I recommend the `str_replace` or `str_replace_all` methods, ([documentation found here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html))

```
library(tidyverse)

data$Model <- str_replace(data$Model, "Toyouta", "Toyota")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use regular expressions and `case_when`
It's difficult to offer solutions without seeing your data, but here's a potential solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(make = case_when(
    str_detect(str_to_lower(Make), "^toy") ~ "Toyota",
    TRUE ~ Make
  ))
```